# After deleting a folder, Xcode will prebuild but never build. Xcode 9.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm working on some SpriteKit stuff in my game and I came across an issue.

I have been working on some animations for my main character and I have to drag/drop the folder containing the images into my project navigator. This works, but the issue pops up when I delete the folder containing the images. After doing this I try to run the app. It starts "prebuilding" and won't ever finish. This forces me to have to force-quit Xcode and start it back up again.

[image: Image 1]
*this is what it is telling me*

Is this a bug? Or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Bug, restart Xcode (probably have to do a force quit), the current version simply is completely broken.

Comment: Thats the thing. It repeatedly happens over and over again, no matter how many times I restart Xcode.

Comment: I have faced this issue. Force quitting Xcode and restarting works and then I was able to build and run the project. Also simply running the project also used to build and run the project for me.

Comment: Yes, the latest Xcode version is a disgrace, this is one of the minor big issues. Plenty more are there, Xcode itself, in particular Playgrounds crash regularly, etc.

Comment: Let me check the AppStore for an update. EDIT: nope...well, looks like we are going to have to just live with this bug.

Comment: If you want to feel a little better and see that you are not the only one take a look at the official apple forums, the rage is real there.